# Calculate date time difference of two columns with null value in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I had a dataframe like below:

```
    startdate   terminationdate
0   1997-07-13  2004-09-29
1   1999-07-26  2016-03-23
2   2003-04-01  NaT
3   2007-06-01  NaT
4   2009-06-01  NaT
```

I would like to get the output to calculate the tenure in months. For null value in terminationdate, I would like to use current date to calculate.

I tried the code below:

```
def tenure(df):

    if df['terminationdate'] != np.nan:
        tenure = (df['terminationdate'] - df['startdate'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')

    else:
        tenure = (datetime.datetime.now() - df['startdate'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
    return tenure
```

The tenure of NaT value could not be calculated with above code.

Comment: you want `fillna`: `df.terminationdate.fillna(date_here, inplace=True)` before substraction.

Comment: Is it null or NaT? They're not the same thing.

Comment: oh, it's NaT actually. Thanks for reminder.

Comment: Probably don't want `inplace=True` as that would terminate the employee.

Answer (score 2):

tawab_shakeel's answer is valid. In case you want to keep the null in the dataset and follow your logic, you can use the apply function to each raw

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'startdate': pd.to_datetime(['1997-07-13', '1999-07-26', '2003-04-01', '2007-06-01', '2009-06-01']),
                   'terminationdate': pd.to_datetime(['2004-09-29', '2016-03-23', None, None, None])})

def tenure(start_date, end_date):
    if pd.isna(end_date) == False:
        tenure = (end_date - start_date)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
    else: 
        tenure = (datetime.now() - start_date)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
    return tenure

tenure_month = df.apply(lambda row: tenure(row['startdate'], row['terminationdate']), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `fillna` to replace the `NaT` in `terminationdate` with current one:

```
tenure = (df['terminationdate'].fillna(datetime.datetime.today()) - df['startdate'])/
          np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

Comment: Nice.  You might prefer `datetime.date.today()` over `datetime.datetime.today()` to get the same precision as the other dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting columns into date using pd.to_datetime()
fill current date using np.where and datetime.datetime.now().date
final apply your formula of difference

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate']).dt.date
df['terminationdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['terminationdate']).dt.date

df['terminationdate'] = np.where(df['terminationdate'].isnull(),
                                datetime.datetime.now().date(),
                                df['terminationdate'])

df['result'] = (df['terminationdate'] - df['startdate'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

Comment: `df['terminationdate'] = np.where(df['terminationdate'].isnull(), datetime.datetime.now().date(), df['terminationdate'])` is a verbose way to write `df['terminationdate'].fillna(datetime.datetime.now().date(), inplace=True)`.  Also `datetime.datetime.now().date()` is a verbose way to write `datetime.date.today()`. But why even mutate terminationdate?  Just do `df['result'] = (df['terminationdate'].fillna(datetime.date.today()) - df['startdate']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski you are right your solution is most precise